# Export Release Build does not work properly

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flash-builder

I have discovered that my project does not work properly when it is exported using Export Release Build. The error is very small: The stop(0) function that is designed to remove the video and unload any remaining audio does not work.

The file works properly in the bin-debug folder. It is only when exported to the release folder that the error occurs. I have tried swopping the 'correct' .swf file from bin-debug with the file in the release folder. That causes the 'correct' file to fail.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute"  xmlns:local="*" >
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            [Bindable] public var videoAddress:String 
            private static const YOUTUBE_EMBED_URL:String = "http://www.youtube.com/v/";            
            [Bindable] public var videoUrl:String = "";                                 
            public function play():void {
                Security.allowDomain("*");
                videoUrl = YOUTUBE_EMBED_URL+videoAddress;
            }                   
            public function stop():void{
                SoundMixer.stopAll();
                swfLoader.unloadAndStop(true)
            }
            public function playVideo(buttonNumber:int):void{
                    stop()
                switch(buttonNumber){                       
                    case 0:
                        videoAddress = "xUWeAOLY0FU?rel=0";
                        play()
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        videoAddress = "m2dg6teC7fg?rel=0"; 
                        play()
                        break;                  
                    default:                            
                        break;
                }           
            }                       
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>    
<mx:HBox>
    <mx:Button id="button0"   label="Button0"  click="playVideo(0)" useHandCursor="true" buttonMode="true" />
    <mx:Button id="button1"   label="Button1"  click="playVideo(1)" useHandCursor="true" buttonMode="true" />
</mx:HBox>
<mx:VBox id="vBox"    y="50" />
<mx:SWFLoader id="swfLoader" source="{videoUrl}"  y="50"/>
```

How can I correct this error? I thought this might have been an issue with the crossdomain policy, so I added the floowing file to the server, but it still does not work:
corssdomain.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<!-- http://www.foo.com/crossdomain.xml --> 
<cross-domain-policy> 
    <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="by-content-type"/> 
    <allow-access-from domain="*"/> 
   <allow-access-from domain="i.ytimg.com"/> 
   <allow-access-from domain="youtube.com"/> 
</cross-domain-policy>
```

Comment: What is the error? And what is your code?

Comment: The version in the folder for the Export Release file malfunctions, but there is no error code. The version in the bin-debug folder works properly UNTIL the entire bin-debug folder is moved, at which point it too malfunctions.

Comment: What do you mean with "doesn't work properly". This is not clear for anyone except you.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason that the SWF from the bin-debug folder works differently is that the SWF performs some potentially insecure operation (like accessing local files, etc), since bin-debug folder usually is in the "white list" for the Flash player.

So you can either add your bin-release folder to the list of trusted locations (in Global Settings of the Flash player) or, if the app is for the web, just test it in the web environment first and see how it works.

Also, in order to see all the runtime errors you can use the "content debugger" version of the Flash player (http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html).

Comment: Everything works when running locally. There is code that fails when it placed onto the web server. Also, I'm already using the content debugger-- it does not produce any runtime errors.

Comment: you'd better post your code here if you suspect any errors in it, instead of downvoting.

Comment: Ok thanks. I have uploaded a code snippet to illustrate the error.

Comment: Thanks a lot! your advise helped me!

Answer (score 0):

I see that You use Flex SDK 3.6 and FlashPlayer 9. The method "unloadAndStop" doesn't work correctly in FP 9.
Try to use Flex SDK 4.5.1 and compile to FP 10.2.0.